# Requestjs returning original language

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I'm using request.js and cheerio to capture some text of my site. 
The original text is English, and I would like to capture the translated version. 
Here's what I have for the request:

```
request.get({uri:
    'http://immocostablancasofia.com/listing/villa-in-lliber-ref-p01638/?lang=nl',
    'followAllRedirects': true}
```

It returns the English version instead of the Dutch one.
I also tried using formData, with no luck.

Comment: I followed the link and it showed with English version first, but if you go there again it shows Dutch version. I guess it's not the problem with your request.

Comment: shouldn't followAllRedirect solve this then?

Comment: No, a browser follows all redirections, but does arrive at the English version, unless you were already on your site when you paste the url in the address bar.

Comment: So? The '?lang=nl'-part does that. Doesn't it?
I tried it on all my devices and works out of the box in Dutch.
Also tried with chrome rest api and it returns in Dutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code adding ',headers:{'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL'}' , and it works!

request.get({uri:
    'http://immocostablancasofia.com/listing/villa-in-lliber-ref-p01638/?lang=nl',headers:{'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL'}
    'followAllRedirects': true}

Answer (score 2):

Add options for request:

```
var options = {
        url: 'http://immocostablancasofia.com/listing/villa-in-lliber-ref-p01638/',
        headers: {'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL'},
        qs: {lang:'nl'}
    };
```

And

```
request.get(options, callback);
```